# Why does my Sitecore site start rebuilding indexes after a restart even though I'm using the manual index strategy?

Tags: content-search, indexing, lucene

I'm using `Sitecore 9.2 XM` and (don't shoot me for this) Lucene search provider...
I want to do some investigation and timing, so patched all my search indexes to use the manual indexing strategy, but despite this, when Sitecore restarts following the config change, a rebuild of all the indexes starts again.

Is/are there some other setting(s) affecting this?

Comment: Did you confirm your strategy in Showconfig already? check if you have only a manual index strategy.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal yes, confirmed that my patch did the trick already. Used some patch:delete elements along with adding in the manual strategy and looking as intended there.

Comment: It could be a scheduled task or an event triggering this. Check your config-driven `<agent>` tasks and the content-driven tasks in `/sitecore/system/Tasks`. Also check the `EventQueue`-table in the `master` database. A bit far fetched, but perhaps there is a queued rebuild there.